what is the best vscode extension for html dom api Hints?
I am writing html files. how get
Ctrl+Shift+Space not work
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillText?


VSCode has excellent support for web development outside the box.
The issue is, when you fetch an element from the HTML DOM tree using id or css class, the element is fetched as a HTMLElement or Element
Since the id or class can be applied to any Element VSCode is not aware of the type of the Element being fetched.
To ensure the type of the element is known to VSCode, one of these two approaches can be taken:
1. Specify the Type of the Element being fetched using comments
You can specify the type of the elements being used through TypeDefinition comments, VSCode will parse these comments and assign the correct value
In your case by assigning type HTMLCanvasElement to canvas, VSCode will have type completion for the HTMLCanvasElement.
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

2. Explicitly specify the element being fetched using document.querySelector
If we explicitly specify the type of the element when using css query selectors, VSCode is able to infer the type of the element being fetched.
In your case we will use the query selector canvas#myCanvas to fetch the canvas
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas#myCanvas');

This way VSCode knows that the element being fetched in a HTMLCanvasElement and it will allocate the appropriate type.
